# How to upload to azure blob from a dataset or a datatable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am currently working in `Powershell`, trying to get some data from my `Azure SQL Database`. I have with success fetched some data into a dataset. However, i cannot seem to figure out how to upload it to `Azure blob storage` without saving it locally first as a csv.

> The dataset must be converted to csv and uploaded to the blob as a csv without saving it locally.

This is what  got so far:

```
$SQLServer = "xxxxxxx"
$SQLDBName = "xxxxxx"
$uid ="xxxxxxxx"
$pwd = "xxxxxxx"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from Dim.xxxxxx;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$csv = $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $csv -Context $context -Container "xxxxxx"
```

However the last line gives me this error:

> Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the
>   type 'System.String' required by parameter 'File'. Specified method is
>   not supported.

I know im doing something wrong but i cannot figure out how to convert the dataset and upload it at the same time. Or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A solution I found was to create an temporaryfile in `Powershell` instead.

First I declare a variable with the `New-TemporaryFile.` After this I take my `DataSet` and export it to `$file` Variable. And after I have done that i can upload it to my `Azure Blob Storage`.

So the solution is:

```
$file = New-TemporaryFile
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $file -Container "xxxxxx" -Context $context -blob "dataset" -Force
```

Comment: This solution saves the file locally, which was an option explicitly excluded in the question. It obviously works, though :-)

Comment: @RodolfoGrave Not when its runned by Azure Automation

Comment: You are the owner of the question so you should know better than anyone what you want, but the documentation for New-TemporaryFile is very clear:

The New-TemporaryFile cmdlet creates an empty file that has the .tmp file name extension. This cmdlet names the file tmpNNNN.tmp, where NNNN is a random hexadecimal number. The cmdlet creates the file in your $Env:Temp folder.

This cmdlet creates temporary files that you can use in scripts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile?view=powershell-6

Comment: No jealosy at all :-) I'm just trying to make sure whoever is coming to SO looking for the answer to your original question, where it was explicitly stated that the file shouldn't be saved locally (which is what makes this question interesting), can find a valid answer.

If you can save the file locally then the solution is trivial.

Comment: @RodolfoGrave Yes for some part your right. I forgot to mention im running this with azure automation accounts. And here New-TemporaryFile is saved to the env::Temp. This allows me to run it without saving it to my harddrive or ftp etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201613/discussion-between-rodolfo-grave-and-sqlkindaguy).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for the Set-AzStorageBlobContent, this is not possible:

> The Set-AzStorageBlobContent cmdlet uploads a local file to an Azure Storage blob.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-2.8.0

The reason you are receiving that error message is because the command is expecting a file name, as a string, as the value for the -File parameter, not the content of the blob. Even if you converted the Object[] to a String, it still would not work as the command will try to find a file with that path.

I recommend you use the Blob Storage REST API to achieve this, in particular the [Put Blob method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob). You will have to craft an HTTP request.

The other option is to use the [Blob Storage .NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet#code-example), as you are able to use .NET classes from Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Just let Databricks manage it. The SQL Data Warehouse connector for Databricks will manage the intermediate storage. Just load your dataframe, then write to DW using the DW connector.

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html

Comment: Thanks - Dude to lack of permissions to the blob I cannot do this. I however fixed it with New-TemporaryFile in powershell